# Insert values in col1 of list 1 from col 2 of list 2 based on a common column

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, linq, join

List 1:

```
|      User Id        |    Latest        |
+---------------------+------------------+
|          1          |         1        |
|          2          |         3        |
|          3          |         3        |
|          4          |         0        |
```

List 2:

```
|      User Id        |    Latest        |        Rating    |
+---------------------+------------------+------------------+
|          1          |       null       |       10         |
|          2          |       null       |       12         |
|          3          |       null       |       11         |
|          4          |       null       |       16         |
```

I want to insert the values of the `Latest` column of `List1` into the `Latest` column of `List2` based on joining/comparing values of the `User Id` column in both lists.

I can use a foreach loop but that would run n*m I guess and look ugly. Is there a way to do it with LINQ or efficiently?

Regards.
Junaid

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why don't you give us your sample data via https://dotnetfiddle.net/ with the corresponding result?

Comment: and you want to save list2 in database ?

Comment: please checkmark the correct answer 

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = from i1 in List1
             join i2 in List2
             on i1.UserId equals i2.UserId
        select new
        {
            i2.UserId,
            i1.Latest,
            i2.Rating
        };
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this. this may fix your issue with adding the Latest value from List1 to List2.

```
List2.AddRange(List1.Select(user => new List1{
     Latest = user.Latest, 
     UserID = user.UserID
   }));
```

Answer (score 2):

you can  do it with `LINQ` :

Try this code :

```
List2.ForEach(item1 => 
{ 
    item1.Latest = List1.FirstOrDefault(item2 => item2.UserId == item1.UserId)?.Latest; 
});
```

Note That, `Latest` must be `Nullable`.

Answer (score 2):

> LINQ will never change any of the source sequences, it can only extract data from it.

You will have to enumerate over the extracted data to update your original tables.

```
var recordsToUpdate = List2.Join(List1,    // join List2 and List1
    list2Row => list2Row.UserId,           // from every row in List2 take UserId
    list1Row => list1Row.UserId,           // from every row in List1 take UserId
    (list2Row, list1Row) => new            // when they match make one new object
    {
        Id = list2Row.UserId,              // take UserId from list2
        Latest = list1Row.Latest,          // take Latest from list1
        Rating = list2Row.Rating,          // take Rating from list2
    })
    .ToList();                             // execute the query
```

I don't know how you update your records. Entity framework? SQL? it will be something like this:

```
foreach (var recordToUpdate in recordsToUpdate)
{
     UpdateRecord(recordToUpdate.UserId, recordToUpdate.Latest, recordToUpdate.Rating)
     // TODO: implement this function
}
```